# NHibernate session management in WCF application

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

I am building a WCF application, using NHibernate for the persistence layer. A lot of documentation thats out there is about using NHibernate with ASP.NET applications. But very little on the best ways to manage NHibernate Sessions in a WCF application.

After reading up on [Instance Management Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx) in WCF applications, I am going to use "per-call Services". Drawing parallel with ASP.NET, this is like opening NHibernate sessions on `Application_BeginRequest` and closing them on `Application_EndRequest`. Billy McCafferty's [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) has a great example of doing this very elegantly. But I am finding it a little hard to use a similar concept in a WCF application.

Any code samples or pointers to blogs with examples, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.igloocoder.com/archive/2009/04/23/wcf-and-nhibernate-redux.aspx  -> https://igloocoder.net:8443/svn/IglooCommons/trunk/src/IglooCoder.Commons/WcfNhibernate/

Answer (score 5):

I found another good example -

http://realfiction.net/go/133